# How to change/redefine function by itself

Tags: jquery, function

I want to run function in jQuery, but change/redefine this function, when it is finished.

[**jsFiddle EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/Nwxzb/)

HTML

```
<div id="test">TEST</div>
```

jQuery

```
function yes() {
    alert('yes');

    // I dont know how, but i mean something like :
    //this.fn.function yes(){ 
    //   alert('no');
    //};
};

$('#test').click(function () {
    yes();
});
```

Comment: Why? If you explain the use case, there might be a better solution suggested.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to change functions like that. Perhaps you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Nwxzb/2/

Comment: @Majid Fouladpour I explained questin as simple, as I could... I want to rewrite/redefine function by itself. Becouse, I dont want this function on server any more... for any reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function yes() {
    alert('yes');

    yes = function(){alert('no');};
};
```

Comment: I think he wants to alert 'yes' and then alert 'no'.

Comment: Sorry buddy, I didn't understand that. Anyway, he says "when it is finished". So, my guess is he wants to do something and when that's done do something else.

Answer (score 0):

> [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Nwxzb/4/)

It would be better if you try to explain what the exact purpose for this is. As for your current question, create another function to do that

```
function yes() {
   alert('yes');

    no();
};

function no(){
   alert('no');
}

 $('#test').click(function () {
    yes();
 });
```

Comment: <<How to change/redefine function by itself>> This is how i understand the question but this is for sure not answering the purpose of this. Maybe it is just a school work or something like that